# Index of two same variables

Tags: python, list

I have a problem, where an element appears twice in a list, but when I want the index, I only get the index of the first one.

```
list1=['a','b','c','a','d']
for letter in list1:
    print(list1.index(letter))
```

But I want it to return 3 for the second 'a'.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want all the indexes or the index of last occurrence?

Comment: @Tushar: Based on them looping the whole `list`, I'm guessing they really just want `enumerate` (which reduces the work to `O(n)`, where the current design is `O(n**2)`).